# Many queries in solidity and Gas and Limitations issue

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm programming a social media Dapp using Solidity.
Many queries must be executed. For example, user's posts, following posts, posts with the most comments, liked posts, etc.
I have two ways to do this:

**1) Define the following mapping:**

```
    PostStruct[] posts;
    mapping(address => PostStruct[]) postsByUser;
    mapping(address => PostStruct[]) postsByFollowing;
    mapping(address => PostStruct[]) postsByFollowers;
    // Another mapping
```

**2) Use for loop for filtering and sorting**

Which method do you suggest?‌ Which one will cost less?

Comment: Having `mapping(address => PostStruct[])` is a bad idea, solidity will create a copy of each PostStruct, solidity doesn't have references like other languages.

Comment: Thank you @Ismael, So what's your idea?

Comment: As everything in engineering an extra indirection seems to solve it. Use a 'main mapping' that maps from an Id (uint) to a PostStruct `mapping(uint => PostStruct) posts`. Then when needed to reference a PostStruct use the Id, so the mappings will look like `mapping(address => uint[])`.